# How does Stratified Sampling Work in Weka

Tags: data-science, weka, sampling

I have a dataset. I want to split the dataset using Stratified Sampling. I would like 70%  of data in training set and 30% in test set. So I split the dataset 10 equal subset using `StratifiedRemoveFold` filter in weka. Then I append 7 datasets to make 70% training dataset and append rest of 3 datasets to make 30% training dataset. However, this is not a good option. I found that, for the 1st attribute of test test one value was missing. Like, my 1st attribute has 7 values. But there were only 6 values for 1st attribute in the test set. As a result when I run the classifier on training set there was error `Training set and Test set are incompatible`.

I went through the link [Stratified Sampling in WEKA](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/hyperkitty/list/wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz/thread/KE5KOSUMMCLVORHBSNA54U6SHS6O57XF/). I found `if I want to generate a 5% subsample, set the folds to 20.` If this is the strategy, then for 30% test set do I need to set the `numberofFold` of `StratifiedRemoveFold` filter = 120? And also what about the test set? What should I set as numberofFolds in test set where test set is 70% of whole dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the supervised Resample ([weka.filters.supervised.instance.Resample](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/supervised/instance/Resample.html)) filter instead, with *no replacement* and a *bias factor of 0* (to use the distribution of the input data). When using the *invert* flag, you get the remainder of the dataset.

Comment: Yeah I could try. But this is my project requirement to divide dataset using Stratified filter method. How could I divide the 70% 30 % using Stratified sampling?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use StratifiedRemoveFolds, then use 10 folds, apply the filter 10 times to get all the 10 folds out and then combine 7 to make your 70% and the remainder to get your 30%.

Comment: This procedure gives me error which I described above.

Comment: StratifiedRemoveFolds does not modify the dataset structure, it only operates on the rows. As long as you save your datasets as ARFF, you'll be fine (I just tested that with the anneal UCI dataset).

Comment: How many subsamples have you created? Did you remove the the missing values from anneal dataset? I use StratifiedRemoveFolds filter in the iris dataset which is the default dataset of weka. Divide the dataset into 10. I got those error *Train and test set are not compatible. Would you like to automatically wrap the classifier in an "InputMappedclassifie" before proceeding*  If I press No. I got the 2nd error **Problem evaluting classifier. Train and test set are not compatible. Class index differ 5!=83**

Comment: I called the StratifiedRemoveFolds filter 10 times, for the 10 different folds (each time from the original dataset, updating the fold parameter each time accordingly). They all had the same structure. The anneal dataset has a label "?" and no missing values (anneal.orig has missing values - see [Weka download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/datasets/datasets-UCI/)). You must have done something wrong to get a dataset derived from iris with 83 attributes (incorrect) and one with 5 (correct).

Comment: What do you mean by updating the fold parameter each time? Is it like selecting fold 1, fold 2, fold 3, fold 4.......? How could you append the dataset? What operating system do you use? Can we have a chat? Are you a member of any slack or other account?

Comment: Yes, extracting each fold separately. hence 10 runs (kind of obvious). The simplest is using a text editor to combine the `@data` sections of the ARFF files (they are just text files). Otherwise, use `weka.core.Instances append` (which you already know) or custom Java/Groovy/Jython code.